# Displaying corresponding data from jQuery JSON on selecting from check-box

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, json

Have worked out a small code to allow me to click on a variable and showcase corresponding data for the same on clicking the button. However this does not seem to be happening and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with it.

Would appreciate any help in this regard as I have reworked the code multiple times but to no avail.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var StatJSON = {
            "Opt1":  {
                "Name": "Mat",
                "Parameter1": "65",
                "Parameter2": "30"
            },
            "Opt2": {
                "Name": "Mik",
                "Parameter1": "62",
                "Parameter2": "40"
            }
        };

        $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
            $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
                var this_input = $(this);
                if (this_input.is(':checked')){
                  resultString += [StatJSON.$(this).val()];
                }

                $('#divResult').html(resultString);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        Options:
        <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt1">Option1
        <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt2">Option2
        <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt3">Option3
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" />
        <br /><br />
        
        <div id="divResult"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

- `var resultString = '';` before `.each`
- `StatJSON[$(this).val()]` instead of `[StatJSON.$(this).val()];`
- `$('#divResult').html(resultString);` after the `.each()` loop .. if you need it inside use `.append()` instead of `html()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var StatJSON = {
  "Opt1":  {
    "Name": "Mat",
    "Parameter1": "65",
    "Parameter2": "30"
  },
  "Opt2": {
    "Name": "Mik",
    "Parameter1": "62",
    "Parameter2": "40"
  }
  };
  $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){ 
    var resultString = '';
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
      var this_input = $(this);
      if (this_input.is(':checked')){
        resultString += PrintHtml(StatJSON[$(this).val()]);
      }
    });
      $('#divResult').html(resultString);
  });
});


function PrintHtml(obj){
  var html='<div class="opt">'; // create div for opt with opt class
  if(obj){   // if obj is true
    $.each(obj ,function(k , v){  // loop through the obj and get key and value
      html += '<div>'+k +' : '+ v + '</div>';
    });
  }
  html += '</div>'; // close opt div
  return html;
}
```

```css
.opt{
  margin : 10px;
  padding : 10px;
  background : #eee;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>

    <body>
    Options:
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt1">Option1
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt2">Option2
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt3">Option3
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" />
    <br /><br />
    <div id="divResult"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed! Thanks a million! The above correction worked like a charm. :) The only issue I'm facing is that when I'm removing ['Name'] from the  //resultString += StatJSON[$(this).val()]['Name'];// code in order to get the entire value, it's returning an  [object Object] error. How do I get the entire value for the JSON element? Thanks again!!!!

Comment: Also, if possible, you could also help me with how I can ensure that the row headings, 'Name', 'Parameter1', 'Parameter2' appear on the left side for everytime a selection is displayed below. Once again, really appreciate the help!! :)

Comment: Hi @MithunUchil answer updated with `PrintHtml(obj)` function you can change the html in it up to your need

Comment: Hi @Mohamed-Yousef! Thanks again! This works, but as the index (key) element remains the same for all selections, is there a way where the index appears in the same position for each selection and the elements (values) keep appearing on the right side every time a selection is made? This would allow me to compare the elements in a single table for multiple selections. Super thanks again for taking out the time and effort for these naive questions from a complete beginner.... :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use square bracket notation [] to access the properties in an object / StatJson dynamically. You should also check before whether the property is in the object or not before assigning the value to the `resultString`

```js
       $(document).ready(function(){
            var StatJSON = {
            "Opt1":  {
                "Name": "Mat",
                "Parameter1": "65",
                "Parameter2": "30"
            },
            "Opt2": {
                "Name": "Mik",
                "Parameter1": "62",
                "Parameter2": "40"
            }
        };

        $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
            $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
                var this_input = $(this);
                let resultString = '';
                if (this_input.is(':checked')){
                 if(StatJSON[$(this).val()]) {
                   resultString += StatJSON[$(this).val()]['Name'];
                 }
                 console.log(StatJSON[$(this).val()]);
                }
            $('#divResult').html(resultString);
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>

    <body>
    Options:
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt1">Option1
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt2">Option2
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt3">Option3
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" />
    <br /><br />
    <div id="divResult"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Missing form tag
2. Checkbox without end tag
3. Get StatJSON using properties

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var StatJSON = {
        "Opt1":  {
            "Name": "Mat",
            "Parameter1": "65",
            "Parameter2": "30"
        },
        "Opt2": {
            "Name": "Mik",
            "Parameter1": "62",
            "Parameter2": "40"
        }
    };
  
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
        var resultString = '';
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            let opt = StatJSON[$(this).val()];
            if(opt)
                resultString += opt.Name;    
        });
        $('#divResult').html(resultString);
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Submit?')">
    Options:
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt1" />Option1
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt2" />Option2
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt3" />Option3
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<br /><br />
<div id="divResult"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

And especially to @Mohamed-Yousef. While the solution provided by @Mohamed-Yousef works perfectly, the only issue I'm still facing is that it gives me separate tables one below the other for each selection.

However, as the key element remains the same for all the selections, is there a way where the key element (row heading) appears in the same position for each selection and the values (column) keep appearing on the right side as a column every time a selection is made?? This would allow me to compare the elements in a single table for multiple selections which is what I desire to do.

Once again, many thanks for taking out the time and effort for these naive questions from a complete beginner.

Updated code:

```js
        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
            var StatJSON = {
            "Opt1":  {
                "Name": "Mat",
                "Parameter1": "65",
                "Parameter2": "30"
            },
            "Opt2": {
                "Name": "Mik",
                "Parameter1": "62",
                "Parameter2": "40"
            },
            "Opt3": {
                "Name": "Mir",
                "Parameter1": "65",
                "Parameter2": "90"
            }
        };

        $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){ 
        var resultString = '';
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        var this_input = $(this);
        if (this_input.is(':checked')){
        resultString += PrintHtml(StatJSON[$(this).val()]);
        }
        });
        $('#divResult').html(resultString);
        });
    });

    function PrintHtml(obj){
        var html='<div class="opt">';
        if (obj){
            $.each(obj, function(k,v){
                html += '<div>'+k+' : '+v+'</div>'; 
            });
        }
        html += '</div>';
        return html;
    }
```

```css
         .opt{
             margin: 10px;
             padding: 10px;
             background: #eee;
             border: 1px solid #222;
         }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
   
    <body>
    Options:
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt1">Option1
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt2">Option2
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt3">Option3
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" />
    <br /><br />
    <div id="divResult"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```